# vectorising multiple calls of Matlab 'find'

Tags: matlab, find, vectorization

I make a large number of calls to the 'find' function of Matlab.  For example, the following should give the essence:

```
x=rand(1,10^8);
indx=zeros(1,10^8);
for i=1:10^8
    indx(i) = find([0.2, 0.52, 0.76,1] < x(i), 1, 'last');
end
```

Is there a way to vectorize this code to speed it up?  Just including x as a vector creates an error.  If vectorization is not possible, then any other suggestions for speed would be appreciated.  The actual problem I wish to solve has a considerably longer vector in the place of [0.2, 0.52, 0.76,1], so any solution shouldn't depend on the specific vector I provided.

thanks.

Comment: With that example the result is always `4`. Are you sure you want `'last'`?

Comment: right....I've flipped the inequality (in my recent edit) to make it non-trivial.  Just trying to construct a toy problem that captures the real issue in a simple way.  Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Caveat: your loop will give error if the inequality doesn't satisfy for  `x`. Try it with any value in `x` less than `0.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example, you may want to consider using the `discretize` function for this:

```
x=rand(1,10^8);
edges = [0.2, 0.52, 0.76, 1];
indx = discretize(x, edges, 'IncludedEdge', 'right');
```

Note that cases outside of the range will result in NaN.

```
% small test case
% x = [0.5198, 0.0768, 0.6788, 0.9496]
% indx = discretize(x, edges, 'IncludedEdge', 'right')
% answer:   1   NaN   2     3
```

Of course, this will only be applicable if you're trying to find where *x* fits in a well-ordered set.

Comment: what a useful function.  It's fast...reduced calculation time by about a factor of 100 for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For MATLAB versions **R2015a and newer**, the answer from [crjones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48778288/52738) gives the best option using [`discretize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html):

```
edges = [0.2, 0.52, 0.76, 1];
indx = discretize(x, edges, 'IncludedEdge', 'right');
```

Any values in `x` outside the range of `edges` will have `NaN` for their indices.

For MATLAB versions **R2014b and newer** you can also use [`histcounts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html):

```
[~, ~, indx] = histcounts(x, edges);
```

The differences with `discretize` are that you can also get the count of values in each bin (the first output), and indices for values in `x` outside the range of `edges` will be `0`.

For MATLAB versions **prior to R2014b** you can use [`histc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) (deprecated in newer versions):

```
[~, indx] = histc(x, edges);
```

Again, you can also get the count of values in each bin (the first output), and indices for values in `x` outside the range of `edges` will be `0`.

Answer (score 3):

[Compare](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lt.html) your vector with `x` to get a logical matrix indicating the values lesser in `vec` than `x`. Multiply that logical matrix with column vector representing the column subscripts. Use [`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) to find the maximum (last) index that satisfies the inequality. For the case where inequality doesn't satisfy, you will get zero.

```
vec = [0.2, 0.52, 0.76, 1];    %Your vector
indx = bsxfun(@lt, vec(:), x); %Making 'vec' a column matrix and comparing with 'x'
indx = max(bsxfun(@times, indx, (1:numel(vec)).')); %The required result
```

With R2016b and later versions, you can use implicit expansion instead of [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
indx = vec(:) < x ;  
indx = max(indx .* (1:numel(vec)).');
```

Comment: Not that it'll be noticeable in most situations, but [`flip`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) is about 2x faster than `(end:-1:1)`.